# Bitlocker says PIN is incorrect

Tags: group-policy, bitlocker

I have new batch laptops to image, almost all of them are done but 2 of them (same models) have an issue I can't resolve. I enable bitlocker and make sure that its also recoverable by PIN. This works fine, but not on the 2 I mentioned.

- I have them bitlocker using the fast way not the complete disk because they are new
- I have policies enable, they are domain laptops, see screenshots

[image: The policies for Operating System Drives]

[image: Require additional athentication at startup]

- I have made sure that I enter the correct pincode and also see what I type when clicking insert. This is how i done it with all laptops and no problem what so ever.
- Resetting is also done to other pincodes
- disabling protection and restarting the computer and that again enable it to test it, no change here.
- This is the output for manage-bde -status

[image: manage-bde]

Any ideas why it says pincode is incorrect? While I know its the correct one?

Comment: A tpm bug? does it exist update for it from the manufacturer

Comment: I have the newest BIOS firmware. We update it before we do anything.

Comment: You need to include the output of `manage-bde -status`.

Comment: @Greg. Yes, I forgot to also include this. I've updated the post.